# specify openCV version ROS melodic, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am a bit confused here, the problem which happens to me is, I have made a ROS node some time ago, the node has been working just fine, until recently I  decided to install the new `openCV 4.3` (cloned and installed from source). I have done it because I wanted to use the third party library which I wanted to depend on the `openCV 4.3` so I can have some additional options. In my node's `CMakeList.txt`I have defined `OpenCV_DIR` to point the `OpenCVConfig.cmake` of the `openCV4.3`. I think this went through just fine.
From what I know, the Ubuntu 18.04 comes with already installed `OpenCV3.2` and this is the version which is used by the `cv_bridge` package.
When I run the node the problem which happens is:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed
> (tlsSlots.size() > slotIdx) in
> releaseSlot, file
> /build/opencv-L2vuMj/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/core/src/system.cpp,
> line 1092 terminate called after
> throwing an instance of
> 'cv::Exception' what():
> /build/opencv-L2vuMj/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/core/src/system.cpp:1092:
> error: (-215) tlsSlots.size() >
> slotIdx in function releaseSlot

If I have to guess I would say this is because there are two conflict libraries loaded, after running:

```
ldd <binary> | grep libopencv_core
```

I got this back:

> libopencv_core.so.3.2 =>
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.3.2
> (0x00007fe9de973000)
> libopencv_core.so.4.3 =>
> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.3
> (0x00007fe9db2e2000)

So this confirms the conflict between libraries, so since I have loaded the openCV 4.3 (with the third party library) I would say that the `libopencv_core.so.3.2` is loaded because of the `cv_bridge` package. `cv_bridge` is used to get the image from the `sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr`and this image is given as an argument to the object of the third party library (which previously has been built with the `opencv 4.3`)
I tried to debug and the cv_bridge works just fine, but when the third party object tries to execute certain functions, it raises a previously mentioned exception.
I think it is because of the conflict, do you guys have any idea how to fix this?
Or do you have any idea for a workaround? This is frustrating because I am using  the cv_bridge only in one line, just to get the image for the third party library.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352756/specify-opencv-version-ros-melodic,-ubuntu-18.04/) by [marko1990](https://answers.ros.org/users/49364/marko1990/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2020-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There cannot be a binary or a lib which depends or loads two version of the same source, in this case there will always be a conflict.

---

Originally posted by [marko1990](https://answers.ros.org/users/49364/marko1990/) with karma: 61 on 2020-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0